# Adding python packages to ArcGIS?

Tags: arcpy, python, arcgis-10.4

I am using ArcGIS 10.4.1 which comes bundled with Python 2.7.10. I am aware of the fact that to install external python packages, one needs to install "pip". I already have "pip" as "pip" is pre-installed in Python 2.7.9 and in newer versions of Python. I have tried to install the Python module with the correct name "pykalman" from within Windows Command Prompt and not the Winows Python Interpreter. Still, I am getting errors as follows:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using pip?

Comment: After opening the python window from ArcGIS, I have typed pip install <module>, but to no avail.

Comment: Same for me. I use windows command prompt to install packages using pip, see this question on how to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817447/how-to-run-pip-commands-from-cmd

Comment: I tried pip install <module> in Windows Command Prompt, but that does seem to work either. My "pip" is saved in the following path: C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Scripts. I have also taken care of adding the aforementioned path to the Environmental Variables dialog.

Comment: I think that you should run your command prompt application as Administrator. Please, see my answer.

Comment: @SujaiBappaBanerji Please [edit] your question to include the details of what you've tried, and what happens when you try it.  Did you get error messages?  What module were you trying to install and how did you run the command?

Comment: @SujaiBappaBanerji you have the correct path, see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your answer screenshot you opened the python interpreter in your command prompt by typing `python`. This is similar to the ArcGIS (or QGIS) python consoles. This is where you can write python code, but it is not how you install new python packages.

To install a new package, all you need to do is run `pip install <package name>` from within your command prompt (not the interpreter). If you have your PATH variable updated correctly (sounds like you do, with `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Scripts` included) you should be able to run `pip install pykalman-master` in the cmd from any directory.

If this doesn't work, please update your answer with the errors you encounter.

EDIT: I just tried installing `pykalman-master` and that is the wrong package name. Use this instead

```
pip install pykalman
```

EDIT 2: I see your updated error message. You have pip installed correctly, and you have the path set correctly, so no worries about any of that. This is clear because "Collection pykalman" is printed to the console (meaning pip is working).

The issue in this case seems to be a firewall on your network that blocks access to the pypi server where pip looks for python packages. [Here are other people with similar problems](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=pip+connection+aborted&*).

This is really beyond the scope of GIS Stack Exchange at this point, but to save you time digging through forums and to give a little bit more context......

You could either talk to your network admin to open the firewall (and once you read the rest of this you may see why that would be worth it), or you could download the pykalman source code and install it directly. This is really not so hard (don't be intimidated! :) ):

1. go to the pykalman repo here https://github.com/pykalman/pykalman
2. download the zip file of the repo
3. upzip anywhere on your file system
4. in a command prompt, enter the unzipped directory, the one that contains `setup.py`
5. run this command

   python setup.py install

which tells python to run the setup.py file, and install the package into your python site-packages directory.

6. you can now delete the downloaded zip file and the unzipped contents if you want (all the relevant stuff is now in site-packages).

To test that you have installed pykalman (or any python package), run the python interpreter (`python`) and try `import pykalman`. If no errors, you are good to go.

HOWEVER: The problem with installing this way is that it won't automatically install all of the other python packages that are pykalman's dependencies (`numpy` `scipy` `Sphinx` `numpydoc` and `nose`). I'm pretty sure ArcGIS's python install comes with `numpy` and `scipy`, but I doubt you have the others. Meaning, you would likely have to manually install those packages too.

Good luck!

Comment: The first three points are bang on. Thereafter, there are some changes which I have mentioned in my answer to my own question.

Answer (score 4):

To install using `pip`, if it is correctly installed, I think all that you need to do is:

1. Make sure that `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4` is in your `Path` environment variable
2. Use `python -m pip install <module>` from a `cmd` tool

Answer (score 4):

I did the procedure for QGIS but it's the same for ArcGis. My goal is to install 'rdp' (Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm) third party python module. First, run your command prompt application as Administrator. In console, I ran this command:

```
python -m pip install rdp
```

At the next image you can see that it was successfully installed.

[image]

It's also observed that the package was installed in:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
```

Edit your PYTHONPATH and copy above text in your 'Environment Variables'. Save changes.

[image]

Now, when I launch the QGIS application, 'rdp' is already disponible for the Python Console:

[image]

Comment: There is no need to have a PYTHONPATH environment variable set with the ArcGIS Python installation.

Comment: Probably because you can use **pip install** inside Python Console of ArcGis. In my case it's not possible for QGIS so, I need the PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the pykalman repo here https://github.com/pykalman/pykalman
2. Download the zip file of the repo
3. Upzip anywhere on your file system
4. Copy the setup.py file from the unzipped folder and place it in C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4.
5. Run Windows Command Prompt as administrator and change the directory.
6. Run this command: python setup.py install

The output would be as follows:

[image]

Comment: Well, if it works it works, but I don't recommend adding files to `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4`. What you should do is add that path to your environment variable PATH (just as you did with `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Scripts`, and I kinda thought you already had??). That way you can run `python` from any directory, allowing you to use the exact steps I laid out. I recommend that you remove `setup.py` from `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4`, as a house-keeping measure for down the road.

Comment: All right. What I had added in Environment Variables>System Variables>Path were: C:\Python27 and C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Scripts, but not C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4. I will add C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4 to Environment Variables>System Variables>Path  as recommended by you. Even I suppose I should remove setup.py from C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4 to maintain tidiness in that folder. What I do not understand is that when I run Python as administrator, it opens in the following directory:  C:\Windows\system32>, even though I have not added C:\Windows\system32> to Environment Variables>System Variables>Path .

Comment: You now talking about the command prompt, or cmd.exe, not python. If you run the command prompt as a user, it will open in that user's home directory. If you run it as administrator (which doesn't have a home directory) it will open in .....system32. These things have nothing to do with your PATH environment variable.